# Why do you need absolute value when taking $\sqrt{\cos^2(x)}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\sqrt{\cos^2(x)} = |\cos(x)|$$

Is this on the right track?  If you have an underlying $\cos(x)$ that is negative, and then you square it, you will now have $\cos^2{x}$, which is positive.  But, if you now square root that positive squared term, you will just have a positive value of the $\cos(x)$, which is not what you started with?

Comment: More generally, if $u$ is a real number, then $\sqrt{u^2}=|u|$. It's not "a positive value of $\cos(x)$." $\cos(x)$ is what it is, and it doesn't change its value. But the square root function returns a positive value, so when $\cos(x)$ was negative, $\sqrt{\cos^2(x)}>0$ and thus it is not $\cos(x)$.

Comment: A very basic approach: Take a graphing calculator and graph $\sqrt{cos^2x}$  as well as just $cosx$ and see the difference...

Comment: $\sqrt{\cos^2(x)}\neq\cos(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: $cos(\pi) = -1$   so $cos^2(\pi) = 1$     but $\sqrt{cos^2(\pi)} = \sqrt{1} = 1$  therefore  $\sqrt{cos^2(\pi)} \neq cos(\pi)$   HOWEVER  ...........1 = $\sqrt{cos^2(\pi)} = |cos(\pi)| = |-1| = 1 $

Comment: So, what is the general rule when taking the square root of a square?  Always add |....|'s ?    How come you don't do this when taking the square root of $x^2$ ?

Comment: As Thomas Andrews pointed out, you do.  $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Comment: How come in every class I ever took, we just merrily used the $\sqrt{}$ to cancel out the square, and just were left with the inside of the radical, and not its absolute value ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As $(-t)^2 = t^2$, the square root doesn't know which is the sign of the thing-inside-the-square.

Comment: $cos(\pi) = -1$   so $cos^2(\pi) = 1$     but $\sqrt{cos^2(\pi)} = \sqrt{1} = 1$  therefore  $\sqrt{cos^2(\pi)} \neq cos(\pi)$   HOWEVER  ...........1 = $\sqrt{cos^2(\pi)} = |cos(\pi)| = |-1| = 1 $

Comment: So, what is the general rule when taking the square root of a square?  Always add |....|'s ?    How come you don't do this when taking the square root of $x^2$ ?

Comment: If you *know* that $x\ge 0$, then $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ because $|x| = x$.